# How do I get every 'href' attribute from each link I have in my html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get every link from my html code to load on click a div class content from an other page:
I just can't get it right but I already got the first link...
This is my function:

````
    $("a.button.view").click(function(e) {
        links = $("a.button.view").attr('href');
        e.preventDefault()

        $(".wrapper-error").load(links + " .wrapper-order-details");

    });
```
this is my html:
```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/account/view-order/426/" class="button view">View</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/account/view-order/427/" class="button view">View</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/account/view-order/428/" class="button view">View</a>
```
````

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to achieve this

```
var links = [];
$('a').each(function() {
   links.push( this.href ); 
});
console.log(links);
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I have the array I want to display the content of each .wrapper-order-details class div link in .wrapper-error, Any suggestions?

Comment: yes all you have to do is 
loop through and outout
`for (i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    $('.wrapper-order-details ').html(links[i])
}`

remember to accept the answer if it worked for you

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.button.view").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var link = [];
        $('a.button.view').each(function() {
            link.push(this.href);

            console.log(link);
            console.log(link[i]);
        });
        for (i = 0; i < link.length; ++i) {
            $(".wrapper-error").load(link[i] + " .wrapper-order-details");
        }
    });`
I got this but if I click on a link twice it passes both href attributes

Comment: you can make the list unique what  i mean by that is just remove the duplicates 

`function unique(list) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(list, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
  });
  return result;
}`

Comment: accept the answer if it has answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()` is shortest approach

```js
const links = $('a').map((_,el) => el.href).get()

console.log(links)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/account/view-order/426/" class="button view">View</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/account/view-order/427/" class="button view">View</a>
<a href="http://localhost:8080/account/view-order/428/" class="button view">View</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, now that I have the array I want to display the content of each .wrapper-order-details class div link in .wrapper-error, Any suggestions?

Comment: I got this so far but every time I click on a button twice it passed through both href attr. `$(document).ready(function() {      $("a.button.view").click(function(e) {         e.preventDefault()         var link = [];         $('a.button.view').each(function() {             link.push(this.href);              console.log(link);             console.log(link[i]);         });         for (i = 0; i < link.length; ++i) {             $(".wrapper-error").load(link[i] + " .wrapper-order-details");         }     });`